# Manipulating data in DataFrame: how to calculate the square of a column

Tags: dataframe, julia, calculation

I would like to calculate the square of a column A `1,2,3,4`, process it with other calculation store it in column C

```
using CSV, DataFrames
df = DataFrame(A = 1:4, B = ["M", "F", "F", "M"])
df.C = ((((df.A./2).^2).*3.14)./1000)
```

Is there an easier way to write it?

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure how much shorter you would want the formula to be, but you can write:

```
df.C = @. (df.A / 2) ^ 2 * 3.14 / 1000
```

to avoid having to write `.` everywhere.

Or you can use `transform!`, but it is not shorter (its benefit is that you can uset it in a processing pipeline, e.g. using Pipe.jl):

```
transform!(df, :A => ByRow(a -> (a / 2) ^ 2 * 3.14 / 1000) => :C)
```

Comment: Many thanks to both of you @Bogumił Kamiński and Przemyslaw Szufel! As both your answers are equally good, I upvote both of them

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
df.D = .5df.A .^2 * 0.00314
```

Explanation:

- not so many parentheses needed
- multiplying scalar by vector is here as good as the vectorization for short vectors (up two something like 100 elements)

A simple benchmark using `BenchmarkTools`:

```
julia> @btime $df.E = .5*$df.A .^2 * 0.00314;
  592.085 ns (9 allocations: 496 bytes)

julia> @btime $df.F = @. ($df.A / 2) ^ 2 * 0.00314;
  875.490 ns (11 allocations: 448 bytes)
```

The fastest is however a longer version where you provide the type information `@. (df.A::Vector{Int} / 2) ^ 2 * 0.00314` (again this matters rather for short `DataFrame`s and note that here the `Z` column must exist so we create it here):

```
julia> @btime begin $df.Z = Vector{Float64}(undef, nrow(df));@. $df.Z = ($df.A::Vector{Int} / 2.0) ^ 2.0 * 0.00314; end;
  162.564 ns (3 allocations: 208 bytes)
```

Comment: Not doing broadcasting, as you propose is actually much slower than broadcasting everything, as you are allocating 3 times not 1 time.

Comment: Actually it depends on the length of the vector (number of rows of the `DataFrame`) for short vectors algebraic multiplication is faster. The break-even is around 100 rows. I edited the answer.

Comment: But this is only due to type instability of the code in the examples you benchmark. If you made the operation type stable broadcasting everything is faster.

Comment: I added the type stable version to the benchmarks and then indeed for such short vector this is many times faster but the code is kind of long :-)

Comment: Many thanks to both of you @Przemyslaw Szufel and Bogumił Kamiński. As both your answers are equally good, I upvote both of them